# Correct sources.list for debian unstable

Tags: debian

I recently started using the unstable debian repo and updated all my packages to the newest versions. My /etc/apt/sources.list looks like this:

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free

deb https://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free

# buster-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
```

Is this the proper configuration for security? I only changed the top 2 to point to unstable instead of buster, as you can see the other 4 sources still point to buster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to edit your sources as follows:

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
```

Debian Sid doesn't have a security repository.

Debian Wiki: [What are some best practices for testing/sid users?](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUnstable#What_are_some_best_practices_for_testing.2Fsid_users.3F)

Comment: Also, unless you actually plan to download and use source packages, it's best (and faster) to comment out the deb-src lines, avoiding delays downloading source Packages files you're not going to use.   You can always uncomment temporarily and run "apt update" if you ever do need the source for a package.  IMO debian should comment these out by default since 99% of users will never need src pkgs.